# why TextBox.Click event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Tags: c#, event-handling, extension-methods

I'm trying to write a extension method of `EventHandler`, as followed:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void Add(this EventHandler handler, EventHandler next)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

It works fine for my events, such as:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent
```

I can use my extension with no problem:

```
MyEvent.Add((x, y) => { /* do something */ });
```

But when I want to apply it to Click event of a TextBox, I get a compilation error:

> error CS0079:
>
> The event System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.Click can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=`

What puzzle me is, the Click event doesn't look any different from `MyEvent`, so why it does have the constraint?

Comment: How are you applying it to the click event of the TextBox?

Comment: It looks like an event is not an object in the conventional sense (i.e. it doesn't necessarily have an instance). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k9b7wd8(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @ChrisF, I apply it in this way: textBox1.Click.Add((x, y) => {}); and it won't compile.

Comment: Does it work if you do this: `var evt = textBox1.Click; evt.Add(...);` ?

Comment: @flem No, the first line will trigger the error(can only on left hand side)

Comment: What if you declare your event like TextBoxBase.Click (which is really Control.Click); with add/remove accessors? `public event EventHandler MyEvent { add { /*...*/ } remove { /*...*/ } }`

Comment: @SimonSvensson The problem is not MyEvent but events of winform controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Add` method is called from **within the same** class that `MyEvent` is defined it'd probably work just fine.

However, the `Click` method is defined in a **different class** than where you are calling `Add` from. That's why it doesn't work.

The .NET framework doesn't allow events to be directly modified outside of the class that defined it otherwise a bit of rouge code could remove all of the event handlers of any class.

Here's the best extension method that I could come up with that will help you do what you want:

```
public static Action Add<TDelegate>(
    this TDelegate handler, 
    Action<TDelegate> addHandler, 
    Action<TDelegate> removeHandler)
{
    addHandler(handler);
    return () => removeHandler(handler);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var bar = new Bar();

EventHandler handler = (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("MyEvent!");
};

var cleanup = handler.Add(h => bar.MyEvent +=h, h => bar.MyEvent -=h);
bar.Raise();
bar.Raise();
cleanup();
```

The `cleanup` action is used to remove the event handler when it is not needed.

I left out all of the required null-check code for simplicity. You would have to put them in in the appropriate places.

Comment: It's an extension method, highly unlikely it's in the same class.

Comment: @Enigmativity That sounds possible, but I could not test it. Because Click is inside of TextBoxBase which I could not change the code. Can you explain why it behave like that? I didn't found any reason from language aspect.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - It doesn't matter if the extension method is the same class (which it can't be of course) - it matter if the calling code is in the same class that defined the event. Please remove the downvote thanks.

Comment: @Roy - I've provided further detail and added some code for you to try.

Comment: "Please remove the downvote thanks" If I downvoted you, maybe.

Comment: @Enigmativity I tested what you said about events in .NET. That seems true. And I believe that is what blocks my way. Since I cannot modify the behavior of a event(except for +=/-=). I think there is no elegant way to do that. I give up. But thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @ta.speot.is - Thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the two.  A simple example can demonstrate it:

```
private EventHandler foodel;
public event EventHandler foo {
    add { foodel += value; }
    remove { foodel -= value; }
}
public event EventHandler bar;

...
foo.Add((s, e) => { });   // CS0079
bar.Add((s, e) => { });   // No error
```

Remove the accessors and the code compiles cleanly.

I'm going to go on a limb and say that you are unintentionally taking advantage of a compiler bug.  It should have rejected the usage of an extension method on an event declared without accessors as well.  The odds that Microsoft will fix the bug are very low, this has been in the wild for too long.  The best workaround however is to delete the extension method.